# 3 expandable column landscape page in pure CSS

Tags: css

If this can be achieved in CSS:

When not hovered: 3 columns split in average width

[image]

When hovered on one of the column: that column expands and squeezes other 2 columns

[image]

Here's what I've been trying:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* vertical 1:2:1 */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.vertical-divider {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  height: 100%;
}


/* container in page center */

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  background-color: #eee;
  flex: 2;
}

.container>.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: left;
  align-content: left;
  align-items: left;
  transition: .3s;
  max-width: 50%;
  padding-top: 24px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  min-width: 10%;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: left;
}

.container>.item:hover {
  transition: .3s;
  max-width: 80% !important;
  background: #333;
  flex: 4;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="vertical-divider">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="item">
        Column 1
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Column 2
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Column 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

But responsive design (e.g. If I want to just put them vertically if the screen is narrow) seems hard to achieve. So I'm asking if there is a better solution.

Comment: When what exactly gets hovered - the common parent element of those three columns (and it is supposed to work on the first column only), or one individual column (that then itself expands)? And what have you tried?

Comment: @CBroe I've edited the question.

Comment: @Jamesits I've edited my answer to include the responsive requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Flexbox` offers a clean, modern solution. We can transition on the flex property. If you want to make the hovered div take up more room, simply adjust the value to a higher number.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container > div {
  flex: 1;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s flex;
}

.container > div:hover {
  flex: 3;
}

.container > div:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>col 1</div>
  <div>col 2</div>
  <div>col 3</div>
</div>
```

**Edit** A new requirement has emerged: *make it responsive*. Flexbox makes this an easy addition by changing the `flex-direction` property inside a simple media query.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
  }

  .container > div {
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
  }
}
```

With the media query in place, our example is now complete.

[image]

[Have a look](https://jsfiddle.net/1adjygzw/).

Comment: your answer work only in IE10 and IE11.this is not perfect answer.

Comment: @ehsan Tested in Chrome, FF, Safari, etc. Works fine.

Comment: Read more about `flex` property, https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp